# How to Fetch Data from MySQL Database to an Array with One Field as Index of Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table named as demo with fields `id`, `department`, `createddate` and status.

Now i want to fetch all the data from this table to an array with index of array as department and values from each row with same department in that array for example:

```
Array[department]((Array[0]=>id
                            createddate 
                            status)
                  (Array[1]=>id
                            createddate 
                            status))
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: add some of your code u have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach if you can afford to perform a loop on fetched rows and create a new array to meet your required index structure

Once you fetch the db results, perform a loop on the results and push rows into a new array with index as department (I'm assuming its a unique property, and you should even think about renaming it to department_id).

So you easily can do something like this:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query('SELECT id, department, createddate, status FROM demo');
$new_array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $department = $row['department'];

    // To add enter result row including deparment
    $new_array[$department] = $row; 

    // OR to have only id, createdate, status
    $new_array[$department] = 
             array('id' => $row['id'], 
                   'createdate' => $row['createdate'],
                   'status' => $row['status']);

}
```

Note: To have department (department_id) as the index, it must be a unique property.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply...... But i have one more doubt.... if am having two rows of same department nw am getting only one row of result . how to get these two arrays inside $new_array[$department]

Comment: For this keep the value of $new_array as array of rows of same department. So inside the loop, for the very first occurrence of department, initialise an array like `$new_array[$department] = array()`. And then push each the row into this array by '$new_array[$department][] = $row'. To accomplish this, you can use the method `bool array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )` to check if the department index exists or not. If key doesn't exist it means that's the first occurrence, so now you can initialise the new `array()`. And then just add the new row to the end of this array.